# Problems uploading sketch to Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-due, uploading, avrdude

Windows 7 here. I just bought an [Arduino Due](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) and downloaded the Arduino IDE. I wrote a simple "blink LED" program (see below) and am trying to flash it to the Due.

When I connected the Due to my laptop (via micro USB cable), I got a warning on my laptop that it could not find the correct device driver. So I followed the instructions discussed on [this excellent video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCxzA9_kg6s) and went into `Control Panel >> System >> Device Manager >> Arduino` and pointed it to load the appropriate device driver from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\drivers`. This got rid of the warning. Hooray!

I then Verified & Compiled my program:

```
int led = 13;

void setup() {
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(5000);
}
```

Great success! Now it was time for me to upload the program to my Due. The first time I tried to upload it, I got the following error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.4 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"
Sketch uses 1,068 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 11 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,037 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM1": The system cannot find the file specified.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

    This report would have more information with
    "Show verbose output during compilation"
    enabled in File > Preferences.
```

So then in the IDE I went to `Tools >> Port` and changed the selection from `Serial` to `COM3` (again, sort of explained in that video tutorial). I tried to upload again:

```
Arduino: 1.6.4 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"
Sketch uses 1,068 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 11 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,037 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

    This report would have more information with
    "Show verbose output during compilation"
    enabled in File > Preferences.
```

I thought it was interesting that the IDE thinks this is an Arduino Uno. So then I went to `Tools >> Board` and changed the selection from `Uno` to `Duemilanove`, hoping that Due and Duemilanove are compatible for the programmer/flasher tool. This time the error was the same as last, except the first line reads:

```
Arduino: 1.6.4 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila, ATmega328"
```

So at least the IDE is switching board correctly. :-) I should note that my `Tools >> Board` menu **does not** have an "Arduino Due" option. And when I go to `Tools >> Board >> Board Manager`, searching for Due does not turn up anything either.

I also tried running the upload with verbose output, but that really didn't tell me anything more. I'm happy to post the exact verbose output but figured I could omit it here for brevity. I also *did* peruse the [troubleshooting link](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload) that the error output recommends, but it looks like I've already exhausted all of those recommendations as well.

I'm stuck and frustrated, any suggestions?

What do I need to do to get the IDE programming my Due?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... hoping that Due and Duemilanove are compatible for the programmer/flasher tool.

Not even close. You will need to go into the Boards Manager and download and install the SAM support files, select the Due from the list, and *then* upload the sketch.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams (+1) - you got me half-way there. After installiing the Arduino SAM Boards, the `Tools >> Board` menu gives me **two** Arduino Due options: `Arduino Due (Programming Port)` and `Arduino Due (Native USB Port)`. What are these, what's the difference between them, and which one do I want? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, except that they use different physical ports on the board itself.

Comment: `Programming Port` it is! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just had this problem myself..
Unless you use the Boards Manager Menu and install the Arduino SAM Boards (32Bits ARM cortex M3) board info you will not be able to upload your sketch.
After installing in the Boards Manager you will see the Arduio Due programming port and Arduino Native port as an extra options at the bottom or the TOOLS>BOARD menu.
That should fix the problem.(Check which you are connected to and which COM port)
If you still have trouble, disconnect and reconnect the DUE and restart the IDE and if required restart you computer.

This seems to be a common problem when people switch from the Uno or MEGA to the Due. I'm surprised this is not installed as standard in the IDE. I am using 1.6.5r2.

Thanks also to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.